# Find last item in an indexed sequence matching a predicate

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

What is a proper Scala way to find a last element in the indexed sequence (like `Vector`, `Array` or `ArrayBuffer`) matching a predicate, assuming we want the solution to be fast when the element exists near the sequence end?

One could use `seq.reverse.find` to achieve this, but that is O(N), as reverse makes a complete copy of the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [`.lastIndexWhere`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IndexedSeqOptimized.html#lastIndexWhere(p:A=%3EBoolean):Int) defined in [`IndexedSeqOptimized`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeqOptimized.scala#L207) to get the index of the last element matching your predicate, and then a simple `.apply(i)` to get it.

`.lastIndexWhere` in `IndexedSeqOptimized` is defined as a decreasing loop, checking each element for `p(i)` from end to start.

If the element you seek is near the end of the collection this should give you good performances.
Note however that this is still `O(n)`. If, for instance, there are not element matching your predicate, you'll end up checking every elements.

---

Example using `.lastIndexWhere`:

```
scala> val a = (1 to 100).toArray
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100)

scala> def p(i: Int) = {println(s"Checking for $i!"); i == 97}
p: (i: Int)Boolean

scala> a(a.lastIndexWhere(p))
Checking for 100!
Checking for 99!
Checking for 98!
Checking for 97!
res0: Int = 97
```

Answer (score 2):

`Vector.reverseIterator` is O(1).

Comment: This sounds more like a hint than an answer, can you make into a full answer, please?

Comment: i am guessing it should be `xxx.reverseIterator.find(fun)` where `fun` is the condition function. `xxx.reverse.find(fun)` should work on `Seq`

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13` you can use [`findLast`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/Array.html#findLast(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option[A]), which is the reverse of `find` and applies the predicate to match from the end of the collection:

```
Array((10, 'a'), (20, 'b'), (30, 'c'), (20, 'd')).findLast(_._1 == 20)
// Option[(Int, Char)] = Some(20, 'd')
```